# BufferedReader works in standard java but not in android

Tags: android, url, bufferedreader

So I have this exact same code in java and android, but for some reason in android method `get()` always fails to do the job and returns false, but in standard java it works perfect. And I do have Internet permission in manifest.

Here is the code:

```
    public boolean get(){
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(readUrl(url)); // Ignore JSON thing.
            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private String readUrl(String urlString) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            int read;
            char[] chars = new char[1024];
            while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1) {
                buffer.append(chars, 0, read);
            }

            return buffer.toString();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you added the INTERNET permission in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Yes I have, forgot to mention it.

Comment: Print the stack trace and add to your question. It might just be NetworkOperationNotallowedInUiThread.

Comment: ok so you were right I did get network on main thread exception, but how is it possible, the code is run from service that runs on the background?

Comment: @RohitMalish : In Android, a `Service` shares the main thread (aka UI thread) with all other application components. You will need to create a worker thread in the `Service` or use `IntentService` which handles all of its work on a separate thread.

Comment: Ok, thanks to you I have now used AsyncTask to get the content, and everything works perfect. Create an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @GabrielCoutinhoBrêtasNetto : I think you deserve the credit for suggesting it may be network on the main thread exception. Post as an answer and feel free to explain about a `Service` sharing main thread as in my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android when you start a service it still run in the *Main Thread*, aka, *UIThread*, as a good practice you shouldn't do any intensive processing in that thread as it will lock user interaction with your application. So even in a service you must create your own thread to access a network resource.
Here is a reference link to [Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)